# In this queue code my Array size is 5 but I can insert more than 5 element, how?

Tags: c++, queue

This is a code for queue. my array size is 5 but I am able to insert more than 5 element and also can print all of them. how it is working?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int front=0, rear=-1;
int queue_array[5];

void enqueue(int a){
   if(front>4){
      cout<< "queue overflow" << endl;
      return;
   }
   rear++;
   queue_array[rear] = a;
   cout << "Inserted" << a << endl;
}

void dequeue(){
   if(front > rear){
      cout << "queue underflow" << endl;
      return;
   }
   int temp = queue_array[front];
   for(int i=1;i<=rear;i++){
      queue_array[i-1] = queue_array[i];
   }
   rear--;
   cout << "popped: " << temp << endl;
}

void display(){
   if(front>rear) cout << "Queue empty" << endl;
   for(int i=0; i<=rear; i++){
      cout << queue_array[i] << " " ;
   }
}

int main(){
   int element;

   while(1){
      cout << "\n1.Enqueue \n2.Dequeue\n3.Display \n4. Exit \n Enter your choice: ";
      cin >> element;

      switch(element){
         case 1: cin >> element;
                 enqueue(element);
                 break;

         case 2:
                 dequeue();
                 break;
         case 3:
                 display();
                 break;
         case 4:
                 exit(0);
      }

   }
   return 0;
}
```

Also queue all operation is working fine.
What is the reason for that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `C++` doesn't do bounds checking on arrays (for speed) you have to manage that yourself. Better to use a container like `std::vector`.

Comment: You're not updating `front` which you use to check overflow

Comment: Running it [in ideone](http://ideone.com/1QapUW) you get a runtime error.

Comment: Here is ideone link: @Elazar
https://ideone.com/UAZwKd

Comment: I replace the 'front' by 'rear' but still it accept more than 5 element and also I can print it. @jack3694078

Comment: @MASaleh how does "Runtime error #stdin #stdout 0s 3464KB" mean "working fine" ?

Comment: but I can't get my code problem, 
Would you please help me? @Elazar

Comment: Ok got half of answer that c++ array is no bound checking option that why its accepted more input.
But another ques. is why rear>4 is not working?  @Elazar